# Remove required attribute using selectize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, selectize.js

I am using the selectize for selecting the multiple countries. I have a checkbox to select all countries.

Right now I am disabled the selectize field if the checkbox is selected in this way.

```
$("#outbound_countries").selectize({
            delimeter: ',',
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            persist: false,
            create: function(input) {
                return {
                    value: input,
                    text: input
                }
            }
        });
```

And here is my html page

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="outbound_countries" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Outbound SMS Countries: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select id="outbound_countries" name="outbound_sms_countries" class="form-control" multiple required enabled />
            {% for country in country_list %}
                <option value="{{country.iso}}">
                    {{ country.printable_name }}
                </option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <input type="checkbox" name="outbound_all_countries" id="outbound_all_countries" required /> All Countries
        </div>
    </div>
```

So for both checkbox and select field, I have required attribute. If I select the checkbox, how can I remove the required attribute using selectize?

And also if I select the countries in select box, how can I get the selected values from that select box using selectize?

Answer (score 0):

you can used this code that is selectz used to select selectz multiple

```
var Selectz = require('selectize');


Selectz.define('no-delete', function(option) {
  this.deleteSelection = function() {};
});


$("select[name='State-code']").selectz({
    plugins:{
        'no-delete': {}
    },
});
```